# Can't create JSP files in Eclipse Juno - Fedora17 :(

Tags: eclipse, jsp

I just installed this IDE in my Fedora.

I got the following error...

```
eclipse.buildId=I20120608-1400
java.version=1.7.0_05-icedtea
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=es_ES
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64

Error
Sat Aug 04 17:54:04 PET 2012
No se ha podido inicializar el editor.

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.defineClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:188)
at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClassHoldingLock(ClasspathManager.java:632)
at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:607)
at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:568)
at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:492)
at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:465)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:464)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractDOMParser.startDocument(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startDocument(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.startEntity(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.startDocumentParsing(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jst.jsp.core.internal.contenttype.DeploymentDescriptorPropertyCache.fetchDescriptor(DeploymentDescriptorPropertyCache.java:750)
at org.eclipse.jst.jsp.core.internal.contenttype.DeploymentDescriptorPropertyCache.getCachedDescriptor(DeploymentDescriptorPropertyCache.java:812)
at org.eclipse.jst.jsp.core.internal.contenttype.DeploymentDescriptorPropertyCache.getPropertyGroups(DeploymentDescriptorPropertyCache.java:873)
at org.eclipse.jst.jsp.core.internal.contentmodel.tld.TLDCMDocumentManager.handlePreludes(TLDCMDocumentManager.java:966)
at org.eclipse.jst.jsp.core.internal.contentmodel.tld.TLDCMDocumentManager$DirectiveStructuredDocumentRegionHandler.nodeParsed(TLDCMDocumentManager.java:188)
at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.parser.XMLSourceParser.fireNodeParsed(XMLSourceParser.java:135)
at org.eclipse.jst.jsp.core.internal.parser.JSPSourceParser.parseNodes(JSPSourceParser.java:296)
at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.parser.XMLSourceParser.getDocumentRegions(XMLSourceParser.java:173)
at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.text.StructuredDocumentReParser._core_reparse_text(StructuredDocumentReParser.java:355)
at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.text.StructuredDocumentReParser.core_reparse(StructuredDocumentReParser.java:752)
at org.eclipse.jst.jsp.core.internal.parser.JSPReParser.reparse(JSPReParser.java:153)
at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.text.StructuredDocumentReParser.reparse(StructuredDocumentReParser.java:1333)
at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.text.BasicStructuredDocument.updateModel(BasicStructuredDocument.java:2713)
at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.text.BasicStructuredDocument.internalReplaceText(BasicStructuredDocument.java:1923)
at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.text.BasicStructuredDocument.replaceText(BasicStructuredDocument.java:2423)
at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.text.BasicStructuredDocument.set(BasicStructuredDocument.java:2935)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.filebuffers.ResourceTextFileBuffer.setDocumentContent(ResourceTextFileBuffer.java:575)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.filebuffers.ResourceTextFileBuffer.initializeFileBufferContent(ResourceTextFileBuffer.java:286)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.filebuffers.ResourceFileBuffer.create(ResourceFileBuffer.java:245)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.filebuffers.TextFileBufferManager.connect(TextFileBufferManager.java:112)
at org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextFileDocumentProvider.createFileInfo(TextFileDocumentProvider.java:559)
at org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextFileDocumentProvider.connect(TextFileDocumentProvider.java:478)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.doSetInput(AbstractTextEditor.java:4222)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.StatusTextEditor.doSetInput(StatusTextEditor.java:237)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.doSetInput(AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.java:1480)
at org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextEditor.doSetInput(TextEditor.java:169)
at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.StructuredTextEditor.doSetInput(StructuredTextEditor.java:1924)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor$19.run(AbstractTextEditor.java:3209)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:464)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:372)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow$13.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:1666)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:1663)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.internalInit(AbstractTextEditor.java:3227)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.init(AbstractTextEditor.java:3254)
at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.StructuredTextEditor.init(StructuredTextEditor.java:2601)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.initialize(EditorReference.java:324)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:288)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:857)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:837)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:111)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:318)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:240)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:161)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:102)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:71)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:53)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:141)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:889)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:623)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:725)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:696)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:690)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:675)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl$1.handleEvent(PartServiceImpl.java:90)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:41)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:180)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:150)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4291)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:187)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:38)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:197)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:81)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:57)
at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:171)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.showElementInWindow(ModelServiceImpl.java:418)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.bringToTop(ModelServiceImpl.java:385)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.delegateBringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:578)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.bringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:314)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:962)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3071)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$21(WorkbenchPage.java:2996)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$8.run(WorkbenchPage.java:2978)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2974)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2933)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2916)
at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:687)
at org.python.pydev.navigator.actions.PyOpenResourceAction.openFiles(PyOpenResourceAction.java:101)
at org.python.pydev.navigator.actions.PyOpenPythonFileAction.run(PyOpenPythonFileAction.java:85)
at org.eclipse.ui.actions.RetargetAction.run(RetargetAction.java:221)
at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonNavigatorManager$3.open(CommonNavigatorManager.java:185)
at org.eclipse.ui.OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper$InternalListener.open(OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper.java:48)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$2.run(StructuredViewer.java:866)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireOpen(StructuredViewer.java:864)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1152)
at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonViewer.handleOpen(CommonViewer.java:462)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$6.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1256)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireOpenEvent(OpenStrategy.java:275)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$2(OpenStrategy.java:269)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:309)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1276)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3554)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3179)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:916)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:585)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:540)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:638)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:593)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1447)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1423)
```

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3c.dom.ElementTraversal
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 158 more

And it shows me this:

[image: Error]

Comment: Same error when I create a html file, but it works fine. At least, I can see the code editor...

Comment: You've got the wrong java. Perhaps you have gjc instead of actual java?

Comment: When i put this code in terminal: java -version, I have this:


`java version "1.7.0_05-icedtea"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (fedora-2.2.1.fc17.9-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.0-b21, mixed mode)`

Comment: fyi, https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=710815 http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/894203/ ...

Comment: Try using another JVM (maybe 1.6 or 1.7.0), it could be a compatibility issue.